# create array of single ivar from array objects with multiple ivars

Tags: objective-c

if i have an class with two properties "a" and "b" and i have an array of these class instances.  What is the best way to create an array of only only "a" elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html):

```
[yourArray valueForKey:@"a"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the class instances and build your new array:

```
// Presuming some NSArray * classInstances of type MyClass
NSMutableArray * aProperties = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] 
                                 initWithCapacity:[classInstances count]] 
                                autorelease];
for(MyClass * myInstance in classInstances) {
    [aProperties addObject:[myInstance a]];
}
```

If your class is key-value coding compliant for `a`, you can also ask the array for the values directly:

```
NSArray * aProperties = [classInstances valueForKey:@"a"];
```

Comment: Any properties will constitute a KVC-compliant key.